# Input string was not in the correct format C#

Tags: c#, string

I am curious as to why this is giving me an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

This error occurs because the screen is `null` so it should fail the check and not cause an exception.

```
if (double.Parse(textDisplay.Text) >= -2147483647 & textDisplay.Text != null)
```

Comment: What is the value of `textDisplay.Text` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check if it is not null. Also use double `&&` as single checks both arguments. Also you are better off with `double.TryParse` in case when input is in not numeric.

```
if (textDisplay.Text != null && double.Parse(textDisplay.Text) >= -2147483647)
```

Better version:

```
double value = 0;
if (double.TryParse(textDisplay.Text, out value) && value >= -2147483647)
```

Comment: why checking if text is not null? TryParse makes it for you

Comment: removing first check make code a little bit more readable and result would be the same because TryParse works good with `null` values

Comment: @wudzik True, changed answer a bit

Comment: The reason I didn't use tryparse is because the only input it could possibly get was numerical, because it is a calculator. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` and it won't raise exception and return boolean if it is valid

```
double res = 0;
if(double.TryParse("asd", out res))
{
   var a = res;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try && instead

```
if (double.Parse(textDisplay.Text) >= -2147483647 && textDisplay.Text != null)
```

or

```
double @num;

if(double.TryParse(textDisplay.Text, out @num) && @num >= -2147483647)
    return @num;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (double.Parse(textDisplay.Text) >= -2147483647 & textDisplay.Text != null)
```

You should use double '&':

```
if (double.Parse(textDisplay.Text) >= -2147483647 && textDisplay.Text != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParse` so It will not throw any error when TextBox value is empty or null

```
double displayValue = 0;
double.TryParse(textDisplay.Text, out displayValue)

if (displayValue >= -2147483647)
```